# accessing a USB device using FTDI D2XX driver

Tags: drivers, usb, mount, udev

I am trying to access a USB mass-storage device (happens to be a Cycleops Joule 1.0 cycling computer) on my Ubuntu 14.04 box.  There exists open-source software called GoldenCheetah that is intended to provide similar functionality to the proprietary software that typically ships with these kinds of devices.  After much effort I have been unable to successfully read from my device through OpenCheetah, and a post to its discussion group has not attracted any replies so far.  So, I am down to simply trying to get into the device's filesystem, which would suit my purposes just fine.

The device requires the FTDI D2XX driver, which I have installed.  I have also placed a new file `joule.rules` in `/etc/udev/rules.d`, which consists of the single line

`ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", GROUP="dialout", MODE="0666", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'rmmod ftdi_sio && rmmod usbserial'"`

My hope/understanding is that this will prevent the system from attempting to mount the device using the 'standard' driver, which this device cannot use.  This rule appears to be working, as a 'read' diagnostic program that ships with the FTDI libraries correctly identifies the device when I plug it in, and reports a successful read test.  However, no block special file gets placed in `/dev` upon plug-in.  I was expecting (or hoping for) something like `/dev/ttyUSB0` to appear, so that I could mount it.  But no dice.

Any suggestions on next steps would be gratefully received.  I am a novice when it comes to special files and hardware interfaces in general.

Comment: Check using `udevadm monitor -u` & `dmesg` if you see anything while pluging the device